# Как указать путь создания БД программно

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Если база создается динамически, в ходе выполнения программы, то по-умолчанию он создается на диске c\mssqlserver\и т.д.
Как динамически создавать БД с нужным названием в нужной папке?

Answer (score 1):

Если динамически, из кода, то вроде бы так (указать путь к БД там же, где и EXE):

```
        string executable = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string path = (Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

А вообще смотрите в сторону **App.config**, параметр `connectionStrings`: по умолчанию, строка подключения должна иметь то же имя, что и файл контекста, но помимо имени там можно задать и расположение самой базы:

```
< connectionStrings>
    < add name="SampleContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyBase;Trusted_Connection=true"/>
< /connectionStrings>
```

Если у вас уже создан `DBContext`, то в коде можно переключить БД так:

`context.Database.Connection.ChangeDatabase(databaseName);`

Так же можно указать путь к БД в конструкторе контекста:

P.S. Студия не под рукой, точно проверить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

При создании контекста бд можно указать или название параметра connection string файла конфигурации (Web.Config, или App.config)

```
 < connectionStrings>
    < add name="SampleContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"             connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyBase;Trusted_Connection=true"/>
< /connectionStrings>
```

или переопределением конструктора

```
public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public Db() : base("SampleContext") { }
        public Db(string connectionStringName):base(connectionStringName){}
}
```